# INSERT using CSV file with single quote in string field cause error

Tags: clickhouse

INSERT using CSV file with single quote in string field cause error for scenarios like this

```
"'Catbug' Animated Series In The Works From 'Adventure Time ..."
```

But other scenarios with single quote loads successfully. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable to interpret single quote as delimeter by using *format_csv_allow_single_quotes*-parameter:

```sh
echo "'Catbug' Animated Series In The Works From 'Adventure Time ..." |
    clickhouse-client --query "insert into test format CSV" --format_csv_allow_single_quotes 0

echo "'Catbug' Animated Series In The Works From 'Adventure Time ..." |
    clickhouse-client --query "insert into test format CSV settings format_csv_allow_single_quotes=0"
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second example since I call the POST method to do INSERT. I note that INSERT is slowed down after adding the flag. But it unblocked me to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

clickhouse-client --format_csv_allow_single_quotes=0

It because CH does an automatic discovery of used quotes using the first character ' or "